# Find all issues that appear in more than one Agile boards using JQL?

Tags: jira, jql

I need to find all issues which are appear in more than one scrum boards by using a JQL query. or is there any other way to filter those issues?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this question on [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/16384957/how-to-find-all-issues-that-appear-in-more-than-one-scrum-boards-using-jql)and there is answer for this..
the answer is

"JQL is for finding issues based on issue data.  Whether an issue appears on a board is not issue data, it is board configuration.
In other words, you can't do it directly.  You'll need to analyze each board query to see where they might overlap."